# subquery with an inner join

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm stuck on a subquery issue, trying to get multiple columns while using a join.

I'm trying to grab different fields from other tables, based on what the "type" field is set as, for a notifications system that tracks different sections of a site.

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    n.`id`,
    n.`last_date`,
    IF(n.type = 'liked', (SELECT co.`article_id`, a.article_id FROM `articles_comments` co INNER JOIN `articles` a ON a.article_id = co.article_id WHERE co.`comment_id` = n.data_id), NULL),
    n.`comment_id`,
            n.`type`,
            n.`data_id`,
            FROM
                `user_notifications` n
            WHERE n.`owner_id` = 8505
```

The problem, is that phpmyadmin gives me an error of "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

I'm pretty confused, because if I do no INNER JOIN and only grab the "article_id" it works fine.

Comment: There may be solutions possible other than using a subquery. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

Sub-query must return only one column

you can see [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/sql-error-1241-operand-should-contain-1-column)

this query

```
(SELECT  a.article_id 
FROM `article
s_comments` co 
INNER JOIN `articles` a 
ON a.article_id = co.article_id 
WHERE co.`comment_id` = n.data_id)
```

must be something like this

```
(SELECT  a.article_id 
FROM `article
s_comments` co 
INNER JOIN `articles` a 
ON a.article_id = co.article_id 
WHERE co.`comment_id` = n.data_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT co.`article_id`
FROM `article
s_comments` co 
INNER JOIN `articles` a 
ON a.article_id = co.article_id 
WHERE co.`comment_id` = n.data_id)
```

Comment: Okay, so what would be a solution for what I want to do which should be quite obvious?